# How to replace existing primary key with another existing primary key to consolidate two different records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

For the following problem I am looking for the best practice.

We just currently found out that we have one employee in our database twice under different PK in our table as below which is connected to other table with FK_store_employee. 
HR wants to consolidate his record under "Johnson" and move his code from 14 to 15.

[image]

This table has FK constraint to a table called "Store" which is below:

[image]

How I would like to approach to the solution is that ->

1) Replace employee_id **1** to **2** in store table. 
 2) Delete duplicates from store table
 3) Delete primary key **1**.

Is this this best approach? Can you give me any T-sql script sample to solve this with one run script?

Comment: Do a *lot* of testing of your `update` statements and then set `identity_insert` to `on` in order to update the primary keys.

Comment: can you explain what identity_insert does?

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), it *"Allows explicit values to be inserted into the identity column of a table."*

Comment: What is wrong with a simple `UPDATE store SET employee_id = 2 where employee_id = 1; delete from employee where id = 1`?

Comment: @SalmanA after update employee_id there will be duplicated rows so I have to delete duplicates before delete PK from employe table.

Comment: Update dbo.store
Set emp_id = '2'
where emp_id = '1'

WITH TempStore (banner_id,duplicateRecCount)
AS
(
SELECT emp_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by emp_id, id, site_id, store_status_id order by emp_id)
AS duplicateRecCount
FROM dbo.store
)

DELETE FROM TempStore
WHERE duplicateRecCount > 1

DELETE from dbo.empl where id = '1'  . How about this? Is it a good approach? @SalmanA

Comment: You'll need `duplicateRecCount > 1` check too. Having said that, it helps if you post an example of duplicate data (I don;t see any duplicates in the sata you posted even if you change all employees to 2).

Comment: @SalmanA I just edited the sample where there could be duplicate records